# UIBezierPath circle animation distortion

Tags: swift, animation, swift4, geometry, uibezierpath

So, I'm pretty new to animation and BezierPaths. Here's my code. Can you please help me figure out what's causing the distortion?

```
    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let radius: CGFloat = 100.0
    let beginPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center, radius: 0, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)
    let endPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

    circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    circleLayer.path = beginPath.cgPath

    circleLayer.removeAllAnimations()

    let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    scaleAnimation.fromValue = beginPath.cgPath
    scaleAnimation.toValue = endPath.cgPath

    let alphaAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    alphaAnimation.fromValue = 1
    alphaAnimation.toValue = 0

    let animations = CAAnimationGroup()
    animations.duration = 2
    animations.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
    animations.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
    animations.animations = [scaleAnimation, alphaAnimation]

    circleLayer.add(animations, forKey: "animations")

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is to make the circle grow from a center point?

The problem you face with arc animations is that the beginning path and ending path must have the same number of points in them. My guess is that with a radius of 0, the system simplifies your starting path to a single point, or even an empty path.

You might want to instead use a starting radius of 0.01.

Another option would be to animate the layer's scale from 0 to 1 and set the size of the image to the desired end size.

Comment: Hmmm... hate is a strong word, but I honestly hate these kind of issues as either you have to face this earlier to know this or just keep trying different options, because nothing in documentation can or does suggest this might happen. Thank you for saving me some frustration. I've been at it on and off since last night. Setting the radius to 0.01 fixed it.